# Using jquery or javascript to dynamically change select options using bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to dynamically change select options which uses selectpicker from bootstrap.  It doesn't seem to work with bootstrap but without it, it works just fine.
Here's my code:

HTML

```
            <select name="proj" id="project" class="selectBox"  style="width:270px" data-size="5" onchange="tasklist()">
                <option>Select Project...</option>
            </select>
        <select name="tsk" class="selectBox" id="task" style="width:270px" data-size="5">
            <option>Select Task...</option>
        </select>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.selectBox').selectpicker();
});

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","projectList.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

var project=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("project");
for (var i=0;i<project.length;i++)
{
    $('#project').append($('<option>', {
        value: i+"|" + project[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue,
        text:project[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
    }));
}

function tasklist()
{
$('#task').empty();
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","projectList.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
var project=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("project");
var x=document.getElementById("project").options.selectedIndex; 
for(var j=0;j<project[x-1].getElementsByTagName("task").length;j++)
{
    $('#task').append($('<option>', {
        value: j+"|" + project[x-1].getElementsByTagName("task")[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue,
        text:project[x].getElementsByTagName("task")[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue
    }));

}
}
```

XML

```
<projectlist>
<project>
    <title>Project 1</title>
        <task>task 1</task>
        <task>task 2</task>
        <task>task 3</task>
</project>
<project>
    <title>Project 2</title>
        <task>task 4</task>
        <task>task 5</task>
</project>
<project>
    <title>Project 3</title>
        <task>task 6</task>
        <task>task 7</task>
</project>
</projectlist>
```

When I select an option from project, it should load up a set of options for task as defined in the xml file.  So for example, if I click Project 2, it should load task 4 and task 5 in the task option.  This does work if I remove the selectpicker but is there a way I can keep the selectpicker and do this at the same time?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the [bootstrap-select website](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/):

To programmatically update a select with JavaScript, first manipulate the select, then use the refresh method to update the UI to match the new state. This is necessary when removing or adding options, or when disabling/enabling a select via JavaScript.

```
   $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
```

Comment: Thanks! That saved a lot of time

Comment: Came to this post while searching something else and figured out my issue. I was struggling and comparing Elements from last 2-3 hours. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
TypeError: $(...).selectpicker is not a function


$('.def_lang').selectpicker('refresh')
```

Answer (score 0):

TypeError: $(...).selectpicker is not a function

$('.list_doc').selectpicker('refresh');

Comment: This is exactly the same answer as given by @Errr, except for the semicolon at the end of the command. Please do not post duplicate answers. In this case either propose an edit on the other answer to fix the typo or leave a comment below that answer.